# Evaluate $h(t) = t + \frac{5}{t}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Evaluate $$h(t) = t + \frac{5}{t}$$

$$h(-1)=$$

My answer was 7/-1 (Just saw my mistake I added the ones (1) instead of multiplying them)

However the answer is -6. Why is that?

Both denominators needed negative denominators and that caused the numerators for both terms to have positive values, thus I added them. What do I not understand?

Comment: Can you show steps how you arrived at $-7$?

Comment: Does the negative sign apply to the numerators even though they were initially brung into the fraction via the denominator?

Answer (score 3):

$$h(t)= t + \frac 5t \implies h(-1) = (-1) + \frac{5}{-1}  = -1 + -5 = -6$$

Comment: Doesn't the negative 1 become positive?

Comment: Does the negative sign apply to the numerators even though they were initially brung into the fraction via the denominator?

Comment: Dividing or multiplying by a negative number changes the sign of the number: $\dfrac +- \to \,\text{negative} $, $\;\dfrac -+\to \text{negative}$. $\dfrac{-5}{1} = \dfrac 5{-1} = (-1)\cdot \dfrac 51 = (-1)(5) = -5$ And just like multiplication, when both numerator and denominator are negative, they "cancel" each other, so that the result is a positive number.

Comment: I don't understand. According to this function the negative one is in the numerator for the second term (5/-1). When I got "Common" Denominator, I have (1/-1) + (5/-1)= thus it is 6/-1. Is that correct?

Comment: Sure, and then note that $\dfrac 6{-1} = -\left(\dfrac 61\right) = -(6) = -6$.

Comment: Okay I see that now, but as a for my fundamental understanding of the rules. Is my understanding on how things work clear? That is the 1 and 5 in the denominator are still positive?

Comment: When $1$ is in the denominator, positive or negative, we need not find common denominators, since any number divided by $1$ (or by $(-1))$ is simply the numerator (or $(-1)$ times the numerator). Yes, you are fine, and your method works nicely especially when the denominators aren't $1$, so it's a good method to know.

Comment: But why does it not matter? -5 is not 5.

Comment: That's correct. That's why I said that dividing $x$ by $-1$ is the same as dividing $(-x)$ by $1$, which is simply $-x$. For any fraction: $\dfrac{a}{-b} = \dfrac{-a}{b} = -\left(\dfrac ab\right)$. However, $\dfrac {-a}{-b} = \dfrac{-1\cdot a}{-1\cdot b} = \dfrac ab$.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with your notation, or perhaps it is a trick question. You wrote

$$\mathrm{h}(x) = t + \frac{5}{t}$$
There are no $x$s on the right hand side and so replacing every $x$ by $x=-1$ gives
$$\mathrm{h}(-1) = t + \frac{5}{t}$$

I suspect you meant to write one of two things:

$$\mathrm{h}(x) = x+\frac{5}{x}$$
$$\mathrm{h}(t) = t+\frac{5}{t}$$

In either case

$$\mathrm{h}(-1) = -1+\frac{5}{-1} = -1-5 =-6$$

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant: $$h(x)=x+\dfrac5x.$$
Anyway, what this notation is basically saying is: take a number $x$, calculate its inverse $1/x$, then multiply the latter by $5$, finally add it to your original number $x$. So if we do those steps:

- We take $-1$.
- Its inverse is $1/(-1)=-1/1=-1.$ (Because we can write the negative sign *'outside'* the fraction)
- Its inverse times $5$ is: $-1\cdot5=-5.$
- Adding our original number ($-1$) we get: $-5+(-1)=-6.$

Thus $h(-1)=-6.$

Comment: Does the negative sign apply to the numerators even though they were initially brung into the fraction via the denominator?

Comment: @Utvecklaochförenkla Yes, we have that for any numbers $A$ and $x$: $$\dfrac{A}{-x}=\frac{-A}{x}=-\dfrac{A}{x}.\tag{Provided that $x\neq0$}$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}h(-1)&=(-1)+ \frac{5}{(-1)} &\text{plug in }t=-1\\&=-1-5 &\\&=-6\end{align}

Answer (score -1):

$h(-1)=-1+\frac{5}{-1}=-1-5=-6$

because $$+\frac{5}{-1}=+(-\frac{5}{1})=-\frac{5}{1}=-5$$